# Two English grammar questions of past, past prefect

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect

1. Before we had walked ten miles, he complained of sore feet.
2. Nobody had believed him when he said he was innocent.

(1) - Why is past perfect used in the *before* clause when the main clause is *before*?

(2) - Instead of *nobody believed him*, it says "*nobody had believed* (past perfect) *him* when he said he was innocent", why?

Comment: The first example practically *requires* the Perfect verb form, since the walking of (somewhat less than) ten miles *must* precede the complaining of sore feet. But the second example is only "natural" in certain specific contexts (for example, where the narrative reference time is in the past, but focused on some *later* time when people *did* believe him). That's because unlike the walking preceding the complaint, the disbelief *can't* precede the claims of innocence. Note that strictly speaking it's *when he **had** said he was innocent*, but we don't normally repeat the Perfect there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In (1), the past perfect is used because the activity *had not* yet finished - they were still walking. ("Before we walked ten miles" would mean "before we set out".)

(2)  could be used if the person was later proved to be innocent. After the trial, people accepted the 'not guilty' verdict, but before the trial no-one *had believed* him.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer.